# Why Javascript can not read the occupied Value ? TypeError: Cannot read property 'weight' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I got some really weird problem which is supposed not to happen.

The code beneath is a simple function.

But the problem is that I'm having error with the bold one 'truckArray[0].weight'
saying that TypeError: Cannot read property 'weight' of undefined

I checked the value is not undefined with console.log(truckArray[0]),

```
function solution(bridge_length, weight, truck_weights) {
    const truckArray = truck_weights.map((v)=>{
        return {
            weight: v,
            movingDistance: 0,
        };
    });   

    const inProcess = [];
    let timeCount = 0;
    let inProcessTotalWeight = 0;

    do {
        timeCount++; 
    
        if ( (**truckArray[0].weight** + inProcessTotalWeight) <= weight) {
            inProcess.push(truckArray.shift());
        }
        
        inProcess.forEach((v)=>{
            v.movingDistance += 1;
        })
        
        if (inProcess[0].movingDistance > bridge_length) {
            inProcess.shift();
        }
        
    }while(inProcess.length !== 0 );

    return timeCount;
};
```

Please give me an idea.
Thank you

Comment: Isn't your `truck_weights` an empty array? That's why `truckArray[0]` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Please try `truckArray[0]['weight']`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
    if ((parseInt(truckArray[0].weight) + inProcessTotalWeight) <= weight) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if `truckArray` is an array of real numbers and is not an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is probably working for most of the truck weights array.

The problem is in the loop. When you do `truckArray.shift()` you'll eventually having nothing left and so you're getting undefined the next time you try to access `truckArray[0]`. The error is caused when you try to reference weight of undefined.

Tweak your looping to solve that and you should be good to go :)